# Google Calendar ICS file multi event import not working

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, vcalendar

I have tried every example and every solution I have found online and have not been able to get an ICS file to import events into google calendar, ONLY if there are multiple events. This works for one event for google calendar, but not 2 or more. I have a dynamic URL for a client that I'd like to be able to use to auto import events, but I need to get the file import working first.

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated. I am completely out of ideas.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Columbus Commons//Our Events//EN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/New_York
X-WR-CALNAME:Columbus Commons
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180929T120000
DTEND:20180929T160000
DTSTAMP:20180929T120000
UID:event-2
LOCATION:Columbus Commons, Columbus, Ohio
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Harvest Fair
DESCRIPTION:Celebrate the very best of fall with the Columbus Commons. Families gather Downtown to take in games, entertainment, a pumpkin patch, and seasonal craft creations. Enjoy the many free activities or buy a budget-friendly $5 wristband to jump on the inflatables.
For more information, click here!
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20180501T171500
DTEND:20180604T181500
DTSTAMP:20180501T171500
UID:event-8
LOCATION:Columbus Commons, Columbus, Ohio
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Commons Cardio
DESCRIPTION:Want to get a fun, upbeat full body workout in? This class concentrates on longer cardiovascular component interspaced with shorter intervals for body-weight challenges.
This class is provided free of charge thanks to UnitedHealthcare. All participants must fill out a waiver. 
View the full fitness schedule here. 
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I found the answer shortly after posting this. The problem was the DESCRIPTION information is being posted over multiple lines. Removing the line breaks with php to keep it all on one line solved the issue.

Comment: Adam, you may run into other problems if any lines over 75 characters are not 'folded'.   See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5545#section-3.1.  Basically any lines > 75 chars must be split with CRLF and the linear white-space character.      You may find the various ics validators useful - they don't always point out exactly the same things, so i use all of them. There's a list of some here: https://icalevents.com/support/documentation/ics-guides/#validators

Comment: You should turn the above comment into an answer.